# Using a Value to see if action has been executed

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a Popup Window on body click event,
the only problem is that the Popup Window will endlessly open now after every click.

So I thought to use a Value in a hidden textfield and change the value after
performing the action.

I can see in my Google Console that the Value of the textfield gets changed to "1",
but after it still will open the same Popup Window after clicking..

Here is my little piece of Code:

```
<input id="adCount" type="hidden" value="0">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var adcount = $('#adCount').val();    

$('body').click(function(){
if(adcount == '0'){
  $('#adCount').val('1');
  window.open('https://google.com', 'New Window', 'height=600,width=800');
}else{
alert('Popup allready showed');
}
});

});
</script>
```

Am I forgetting something here why it isn't working hmm?

Thnx for Any Help!

Comment: Hi, put this `var adcount = $('#adCount').val();` line inside  `$('body').click(function(){` and try again

Comment: Yes, Perfect!! That did the trick, omg so simple haha! Thanks a lot for pointing this out!